# Every point in a simplex is a convex combination of p and a point in $C^{(p)}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, simplex

Let's fix an arbitrary point $p \in \Delta_n = \{(x_1, ..., x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \ : \ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1 \}$

Could you help me prove that every point in a simplex $\Delta_n$ can be written as a convex combination of $p$ and $q \in C^{(p)} = \{ x \in \Delta_n \ : \ \exists i \in \text{supp}(p) : x_i = 0\}$?

It means that there exists $i \in supp(p)$ such that $q_i =0$.

So given any point $x=(x_1, ..., x_n)$ and any $p=(p_1, ..., p_n)$ it needs to be proved that there exists $q \in C^{(p)}$ such that $$x_k = \alpha p_k + (1- \alpha) q_k, \ \ k=1,...,n, \ \ \alpha \in [0,1]$$

I know that $\Delta \setminus C^{(p)}$ is a neighbourhood of $p$, but I doubt it can be useful here.

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while to understand what you're actually asking. Am I right in translating the statement to:

*Given points $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $p=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$, there exists a point $q = (q_1,\ldots,q_n)$ such that*

*1) There exists $1\leq i\leq n$ such that $p_i \neq 0$ and $q_i=0$,*

*2) There exists $\alpha\in[0,1]$ for which $x=\alpha p + (1-\alpha) q$.*

If that is the case, the first step in solving this, is to understand what $\{\alpha p + (1-\alpha) q \mid \alpha \in [0,1] \}$ actually looks like: this is the line segment between $p$ and $q$.

A next realisation that might be useful is what the boundary of $\Delta_n$ looks like: this is a collection $(n-1)$-simplices. If this isn't quite clear, think of a $2$-simplex, an equilateral triangle, and consider its boundary: this is a collection of three line segments of length 1, three $1$-simplices.

To be more precise, the boundary of $\Delta_n$ is $\partial\Delta_n = \{(x_1, ..., x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \ \mid \ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1, \exists i: x_i = 0\}$. The requirement for two points $p$ and $q$ that there exists $i$ such that $p_i\neq 0$ and $q_i=0$ thus translates to the statement that there's (at least) one $(n-1)$-simplex in the boundary of $\Delta_n$ that contains $q$, but does not contain $p$.

Combining the above remarks, we can now rephrase the original statement in a purely geometrical fashion:

*Given points $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $p=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$, there exists a point $q = (q_1,\ldots,q_n)$ such that*

*1G) There exists at least one $(n-1)$-simplex in the boundary of $\Delta_n$ that contains $q$ but does not contain $p$.*

*2G) The point $x$ lies on the line segment between $p$ and $q$.*

Given the points $x$ and $p$ from the statement, we're now in a position to quite easily find a point $q$. First of all, if $x = p$, just do what the hell you like. If $p\neq x$, draw the line segment starting at $p$ through $x$ and 'consider where it leaves $\Delta_n$'. This is the point $q$ and I'm pretty sure you'll be able to figure out the loose ends from the above. If anything isn't clear, try picturing the situation in equilateral triangles and tetrahedra first.

Notice that I use a rather vague description at the end. This is to avoid writing 'find the point where this line hits the boundary', since that would be incorrect: if there's one boundary component that contains both $p$ and $x$, the entire line segment will lie within this boundary component. A more precise formulation would be: "Let $k\leq n$ be the smallest integer such that $p$ and $x$ lie in a common $k$-simplex in the boundary of $\Delta_n$. The point $q$ is the point on the half-line starting from $p$ through $x$ where $q$ lies in an $m$-simplex in the boundary of $\Delta_n$, where $m<k$." Given the formulation of the question, though, I've got the feeling that this is more complicated than required. If you've got some spare time to think about it, it might be worth it. I'd advise to start thinking about a tetrahedron (where the equilateral triangles at the sides are the 2-simplices in the boundary, the edges are the 1-simplices and the vertices the 0-simplices) having $p$ and $x$ in some of these lower-dimensional simplices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some issues though with writing down the fact that the intersection of the half-line with the boundary  is the $q$ that we are looking for, formally. That is I need to take a point which lies on the half-line, and then plug its coordinates into the equalities: $\sum w_i = 0,  \ \exists i : w_i = 0$. And the one point which satisfies those conditions is the point $q$ that we want.

Comment: How to write down the equation for the half-line? In $\mathbb{R}^n$ the equations of a line passing through $(a_1, ..., a_n), \ (b_1, ..., b_n)$ are $$\frac{x_1 - a_1}{b_1 - a_1} = \frac{x_2 - a_2}{b_2 - a_2} = ... = \frac{x_n - a_n}{b_n - a_n}$$

Comment: Is there a way to find $q$ using the equations above?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't answer your questions. Haven't quite been here for some days. My preference would be not to explicitly give the line, since all that will achieve is totally obscure the proof and make it hard to read, if not impossible. This might actually hold for both questions. I also noticed a minor possible confusion due to indexing: in the definition of $\Delta_n$, you shouldn't use a point $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, but a point $(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$: e.g. the equilateral triangle lies in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with vertices $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$.